# Adding a Sold Out option to price field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

at present I have a basic shop with a price model defined as a decimal field.

```py
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I'd like to be able to keep products visible but add a sold out option.  Is there a way to allow this field to include a blank price or a Sold Out option?

I had also tried testing for truth and displaying sold out otherwise, but this didn't end up showing in template.  Here, my idea was:

```
{% if product.price == 0 %}
          <button>Sold Out!</button>
{% else %}
          </button>${{ product.price }}</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm commenting instead of answering because this is not a good choice of modeling. You should model your data to show how many of an object you have per location, and if that number is 0, show it as sold out. Don't indicate it through a hardcode Boolean. In order to set that field anyway, you will have to count remaining items anyway.

Comment: @dfundako Something like the edit??